# Is an infinite distance traversable?

Tags: physics, infinity, philosophy

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential_energy#Definition),

> The electric potential energy of a system of point charges is defined
> as the work required to assemble this system of charges by bringing
> them close together, as in the system from an **infinite distance**.

This definition implies that an infinite distance is indeed traversable, but how is that even possible? What would an even entity need to traverse an infinite distance? Infinite time? Infinite velocity?

Comment: Think of it as a finite distance, taking the limit to infinity.

Comment: Should I crosspost to physics se?

Comment: "Should I crosspost to physics se?" – Relevant: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/355310)

Answer (score 2):

This is math.stackexchange, so everyone here read $$\textrm{"amount of work performed after traversing an infinite distance"}$$ as $$\textrm{"least upper bound on the amount of work performed when traversing an arbitrarily long distance"}$$ and went on with their lives.

If you want to worry more about this, you should probably take it to philosophy.stackexchange.